# Scala sbt build fails with javafx

Tags: java, scala, javafx, sbt

I've just started Scala tutorial.
I have an error below when compiling.
How can I fix this?

```
"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55919:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/rt.jar:/Volumes/Samsung_T5/Dev/ScalaProjects/nightcoreplayer/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-base/jars/javafx-base-11-ea+25-mac.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.7/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-web/jars/javafx-web-11-ea+25-mac.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-media/jars/javafx-media-11-ea+25-mac.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/jars/javafx-graphics-11-ea+25-mac.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml/jars/javafx-fxml-11-ea+25-mac.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/jars/javafx-controls-11-ea+25-mac.jar" -p /Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-base/jars/javafx-base-11-ea+25-mac.jar:/Users/shunsuke/.ivy2/cache/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/jars/javafx-graphics-11-ea+25-mac.jar jp.ed.nnn.nightcoreplayer.Main
Unrecognized option: --add-modules
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[sbt build fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VuSJ.png)

build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  organization := "jp.ed.nnn",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
)

val osName: SettingKey[String] = SettingKey[String]("osName")

osName := (System.getProperty("os.name") match {
  case name if name.startsWith("Linux") => "linux"
  case name if name.startsWith("Mac") => "mac"
  case name if name.startsWith("Windows") => "win"
  case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown platform!")
})

libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-base" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-controls" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-fxml" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-graphics" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-web" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-media" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not using a correct version of JDK in IDEA.

Install a JDK 8 binary from [download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and follow [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#define-sdk) for idea how to define a SDK.

For the compatible JDK refer to [scala compatible overview](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html).

Comment: (Why not JDK 11?)